# App crashes while streaming radio in webView

Tags: ios, crash, audio-streaming, audio-player, internet-radio

I tried to build a radio in my app using webView. But on loading the link my app crashes every time.

```
    - (IBAction)playMusic:(id)sender {
    NSString *stream = @"http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/listen/live/r2.pls"; //just an example link
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stream];
    NSURLRequest *urlrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [Webview loadRequest:urlrequest];
}
```

...but with a page link (like www.google.com) everything works fine.
Maybe there is also a better solution than using webView to play radio.
Thanks to all of you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIWebView` is indeed not meant to play audio files. I would recommend you to use `MPMoviePlayerController` (part of the MediaPlayer framework) for what you're trying to achieve. I wrote some sample code to below to show how you how to get started.
If you need more information, I suggest you to take a look at the [HTTP Live Streaming Resources](https://developer.apple.com/streaming) or [MPMoviePlayerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio/listen/live/r2.pls"];

MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:URL];
[moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];

[[moviePlayerController view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, [[self view] frame].size.width, 24.f)];
[[self view] addSubview:[moviePlayerController view]];

[self setMoviePlayerController:moviePlayerController];
```

Comment: I tried this but there's an error in the last line...there's no selector 'setMoviePlayerController'

Comment: Don't forget to declare `@property (strong) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController` in your header file.

Comment: However the app crashes after a view seconds and isn't playing any sound

Comment: Ah...I got it. You have to delete "All Exceptions"-Breakpoint...thanks very much